# PHP split array into separated pieces

Tags: php, html

This is probably a beginner question but still have trouble with it.

The following code displays a list of 15 two digit number each row (00, 00...).

Is it possible to 'explode' each line into 15 pieces and put into separated DIV's?

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($combinations, $qty);

sort($rand_keys);

for($i=0;$i<count($rand_keys);$i++){

echo $combinations[$rand_keys[$i]] . "</br>";   

}
```

I am trying to do something like

```
for($i=0;$i<count($rand_keys);$i++){

$pc = explode($combinations[$rand_keys[$i]]);

echo $pc[0].' '.$pc[1].' '.$pc[2].' '.$pc[3].' '.$pc[4].' '.$pc[5].' '.$pc[6].' '.$pc[7].' '.$pc[8].' '.$pc[9].' '.$pc[10].' '.$pc[11].' '.$pc[12].' '.$pc[13].' '.$pc[14].' '.$pc[15];    

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: instead of the echo you'd have to do another `foreach` loop with an `echo "<div>$value</div>"` in it. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: It still doesn't work =/. Thanks @Jeff

Comment: what is your `$combinations` value?

Comment: It's 15 numbers like 00, 00, 00... I want to put each of it into separates divs. Thanks @RazibAlMamun

Comment: i have submitted my asnwer

Comment: Still the same. I think you didn't get the the issue. I want to split each row into 15 pieces horizontally. Thanks @RazibAlMamun

Comment: You'll have to specify what you really want to achieve and what does not work to reach that. If you say "split into 15 pieces horizontally" than that's a matter of css.

Comment: Each "$combinations[$rand_keys[$i]]" is a combination of 15 two digit numbers. I want to split it and put each of them into separated divs. Thanks @Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!

That's the answer I was expecting.

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($combinations, $qty);

sort($rand_keys);


foreach($rand_keys as $rand_key){

$key = explode(" ",$combinations[$rand_key]);

for($i=0;$i<count($key);$i++){ echo '<div>'.$key[$i].'</div>'.' ';}

echo '</br>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `$combinations` values is `$combinations = "54, 00, 65, 87, 36";` like that

Try this :

```
$combinations = "54, 00, 65, 87, 36";

$new_combinations = explode(", ", $combinations);

$rand_keys = array_rand($new_combinations,3);

for($i=0;$i<count($rand_keys);$i++){    
    $pc = $new_combinations[$rand_keys[$i]];
    echo "<div>".$pc."</div>";
}
```

Example :

```
$combinations = array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");

$rand_keys =array_rand($combinations,3);

for($i=0;$i<count($rand_keys);$i++){
    echo "<div>".$combinations[$rand_keys[$i]]."</div>";
}
```

Output is :

```
<div>red</div>
<div>blue</div>
<div>brown</div>
```

Comment: your `$combinations` variable value is like `$combinations = "00, 54, 63, 47";` right?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Razib! I think I could find a better way. Check my answer and let me know what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div>";
echo implode("</div><div>", $pc);
echo "</div>";
```